# How to create and install mvc module with crud funtion in DotNetNuke 9

Tags: dotnetnuke-9, dotnetnuke

I would like to create web application in DNN9. But I am very new to this CMS. i downloaded and hosted in local IIS like dnndev.me. I tried to create one mvc module with crud function and Install into dnndev.me. But its not performing any action. I do not know what i missed. I go through this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUZNPU7-vIc&list=PLFpEtny5sIbbT0spov4It4Z8fswIbNZFd&index=11 but i did not get any clear picture for my Custom crud function. So Please any guide me or suggest me any solution. Thank you.

Comment: Nagarajan take a look at the following github code https://github.com/DotNetNuclear/DnnRestaurantMenu It has a very clear MVC example that includes CRUD operations. This example tends to use best practices as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to DotNetNuke then you can refer this [Link](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/docs/developers/mvc-modules/mvc-module-development.html) to get started with MVC modules.